# Golang отправка json

Tags: строки, golang, http, golang-struct

Столкнулся с вопросом, на который не могу найти ответ.

Я отправляю json в ResponseWriter, затем отправляю GET и читаю в массив структур.
В общем, почему в первом случае у меня не выходит считать, а во втором выходит?

1. Первый случай:

```
jsonResp, _ := json.Marshal(users.Users)
fmt.Println(string(jsonResp))
fmt.Fprint(w, jsonResp)
```

2. Второй случай:

```
w.Write(jsonResp)
```

(Первый случай не работал)

Почему?

Comment: `fmt.Fprint` печатает строковое представление объекта, что-то вроде `[0x01, 0x02, ...]`. `Write` пишет непосредственно байты, без преобразования в печатный вид.